# unknown column "___" in field list

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have two tables in my ty019 database namely tya019 and tya0191. I want to join csa, name, totm from tya019 and cell_n, place from tya0191 and rno of both tables (which is primary key of both of them). Name column is present in both the tables.

When I type

```
select name.tya019, totm.tya019, csa.tya019, cell_n.tya0191, place.tya0191 
  from tya019,tya0191 
 where rno.tya019=rno.tyao191
```

I get this error

> Unknown column 'name.tya019' in 'field list'.

Where I might have gone wrong? Please help me.

Answer (score 5):

You wrote it backwards. It should be `table_name.column_name` rather than `column_name.table_name`

Besides that

- aliases might help make your queries more readable by reducing repetitive long identifiers
- use ANSI explicit JOIN syntax rather than old implicit (coma) syntax

That being said try something like

```
SELECT t1.name, t1.totm, t1.csa, t2.cell_n, t2.place
FROM tya019 t1 JOIN tya0191 t2
  ON t1.rno = t2.rno
```